# Directed Acyclical Graph Crash

Tags: c++, directed-acyclic-graphs

So I am having trouble with my code and cant figure out exactly what the problem is. I am supposed to take in a text file, where the first line shows the number of vertices, and the second line shows the number of edges.From this text file I am trying to take in the values shown then build a graph and determine whether or not it contains a cycle. Then display nodes which have no incoming edges.
t1.txt

```
3
2
1,2,
2,3
```

I am not sure exactly where I am going wrong here.

t2.txt

```
5
5
3,4,
4,5,
2,3,
1,3,
3,5
```

//

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stack>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>



using namespace std;


class Graph
{
    int V;    // No. of vertices
    list<int> *adj;    // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
    bool isCyclicUtil(int v, bool visited[], bool *rs);  // used by isCyclic()
public:
    Graph(int V);   // Constructor
    void addEdge(int v, int w);   // to add an edge to graph
    bool isCyclic();    // returns true if there is a cycle in this graph
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
}


bool Graph::isCyclicUtil(int v, bool visited[], bool *recStack)
{
    if(visited[v] == false)
    {
        // Mark the current node as visited and part of recursion stack
        visited[v] = true;
        recStack[v] = true;

        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        list<int>::iterator i;
        for(i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        {
            if ( !visited[*i] && isCyclicUtil(*i, visited, recStack) )
                return true;
            else if (recStack[*i])
                return true;
        }

    }
    recStack[v] = false;  // remove the vertex from recursion stack
    return false;
}

// Returns true if the graph contains a cycle, else false.
bool Graph::isCyclic()
{
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited and not part of recursion
    // stack
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    bool *recStack = new bool[V];
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        visited[i] = false;
        recStack[i] = false;
    }

    // Call the recursive helper function to detect cycle in different
    // DFS trees
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (isCyclicUtil(i, visited, recStack))
            return true;

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    float n ,n2;

    string filename,line;
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    cin >> filename;
    fstream file;
    file.open(filename.c_str());
    file >> n;
    file >> n2;
    int num = n;
    cout << num << " ";
    int num2 = n2;
    cout << num2 << " ";
    string matrix[num2][2];
    //int ** mat = new int*[num2];
    int mat[num2][2];
    Graph g(num);

    while(!file.eof())
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < num2; i++)
       {
          //mat[i] = new int[num];
           for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
           {
               if(getline(file,line,','))
               {
                   matrix[i][j] = line; // read file into string matrix
                  istringstream(line) >> mat[i][j]; //convert to int and store in dynamic 2d array
               }
           }
       }
   }
   cout << endl << "TEST " <<  mat[0][0] << " "  << mat[0][1] << " " << mat[1][0]<< " " << mat[1][1];
   for(int i = 0; i <num2-1; i++)
   {
        int temp1,temp2;
        temp1 = mat[i][0];
        temp2 = mat[i][1];
        g.addEdge(temp1,temp2);
   }
   if(g.isCyclic())//Here is where the program crashes for input t2.txt
        cout << "Graph is not DAG";
   else
        cout << "Graph is DAG";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem? What have you tried? What exactly is going wrong? Do you get any errors? What are those errors? What have you tried to do to fix those errors? What happened when you did that? Remember to include these things when you make your question. Follow this guide to make sure your questions are of high quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Uh yeah that is the issue, there are no errors shown. The program stops working. Windows simply says that it stopped working properly. Right when i call the isCyclic function. And this doesnt happen for the first set of values input.